# Applying Order Of Boolean Precedence

Tags: search, boolean-logic

I'm just wishing to clarify my understanding of how the order of boolean precedence is applied in expressions. I'll give an example using the following order of precedence:

```
1) NOT
2) AND
3) OR
```

Given the expression, `A NOT B AND C`, I know that `NOT` will be evaluated first. However, will this be applied to the rest of the expression `(B AND C)`, or just the next token, `B`?

My current understanding is that it is the former so this should be evaluated as `A NOT (B AND C)`. Is this correct ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no universally agreed order of precedence for boolean operators, so it will depend on who or what is doing the parsing. For any given computer language this should be well defined in the documentation for the language. Also note that `NOT` is a unary operator (with right-to-left associativity), so your example above is not really a valid boolean expression.

It could be argued that since boolean operators have analogues in ordinary arithmetic, that we should use an analogous order of precedence. In that case `NOT` (analogous to unary negation) would have the highest precedence, then `AND` (multiplication), then `OR` (addition).

Comment: Wouldn't arithmetically NOT be the same as multiplication i.e. `-x` is shorthand for `-1 * x`?

Comment: @Davy8: thanks - yes - I think you're right - at least the C language operator precedence table agrees with you. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The reason I ask is that I'm working on a search system where users have three fields of input that can be connected with the logical operators AND, OR and NOT. The expression A NOT B AND C represents a user search within a document such as MARKETING NOT BUSINESS AND ACCOUNTING. Without parentheses I'm not certain what the expected way for this to be evaluated is. Should it be (Marketing NOT Business) AND Accounting  or should it be marketing NOT (Business AND accounting)?

Comment: @JimS: note that `NOT` is a unary operator - it looks like you want to have an implied `AND` or `OR` operator before the `NOT`, e.g. `MARKETING AND NOT BUSINESS AND ACCOUNTING`, but you will need to think about this, or perhaps consider making it explicit. Note also that typically binary operators such as `AND`, `OR`, etc have left-to-right associativity, while unary operators such as `NOT` have right-to-left.

Comment: @Paul R: Perhaps I should be thinking about this problem differently and approach it from what the user would expect rather than the order of boolean logic.  e.g. Would you expect MARKETING NOT BUSINESS AND ACCOUNTING to return documents that contained the terms marketing and accounting but not the term business or would you expect it to return documents that contained marketing but don't include business and accounting together in the same document?

Comment: @JimS: the problem is that an expression such as this is ambiguous without any pre-defined rules of evaluation. You either have to make a unilateral decision about what the rules should be, or perhaps look at existing systems which allow this kind of expression and then adopt their conventions.

Comment: @Paul R: Yes the problem is that the user input allows these ambiguous expressions to be created. I've seen other systems that have similar interfaces and say that searches are processed according to the order of boolean precedence shown in the original question. This is why I was asking how the order of boolean precedence should be applied as to me the expression A NOT B AND C is ambiguous without parentheses. Interestingly, google don't even use the AND operator (http://www.google.co.uk/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=136861). Perhaps I should post a new question asking what the ideal

Comment: set of operators are for restricting a search.

Comment: @JimS: I think Google and some others use an implicit `AND`, so you can just enter search terms without any operators and then add `OR` or `NOT` as needed.